# how to find number of substrings between delimiter?

Tags: shell-script, grep, sed, awk

I have the string following

> something(1)^^^something(2)^^^something(3)^^^ ... ^^^something(n)

how to find number of

> something(s)

in the string.

Comment: What exactly are you searching for? Any string followed by `()`? Does your string actually contain `^`? Please show us an example of the real data you are working with.

Comment: To continue terdon’s question, are you really talking about strings that end with numbers in parentheses, or are you talking about a bunch of arbitrary strings that are separated by `^^^` delimiters?

Comment: `one^^^two^^^three^^^... ^^^somenumber ` so i want to find the number of string which are delimited by "^^^" delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will do for you:

```
 awk -F " " '{print NF}' filename
```

and you can substitute your favorite field separatorfor the space. If you insist on using ^^^ as a field separator, then you should use

```
  awk -F '\\^\\^\\^'  "{print NF}" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a better answer if you show your real data but assuming you are looking for the longest non-whitespace containing string that ends with `()`, you could do this:

```
$ string="foo(bar)blah blah bob harry(baz) more stuff this(one) not that one ()"
$ echo $string | grep -Po '[^\s]+\([^\)]+?\)' | wc -l
3
```

#### Explanation

The `-P` flag for `grep` enables [PCREs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) and the `-o` causes it to print each of the matching strings only and on a separate line.

The regular expression matches:

- `[^\s]+` : as many non-whitespace characters as possible
- `\(`: an opening parenthesis
- `[^\)]+?\)` : as many non `)` characters as possible until the first `)`.

This would print:

```
$ echo $string | grep -Po '[^\s]+\([^\)]+?\)' 
foo(bar)
harry(baz)
this(one)
```

You then pass that through `wc -l` to count the number of lines.

Comment: Most likely he used `(n)` just to demonstrate us amount of `something`. `1, 2, 3, ... n`. I mean probably it does not end on `()`.